# R How can i count occurrences of a vector of strings in another vector of strings

Tags: r

I am trying to get a count of how many times the strings in a row in a dataframe (dumb_df) appear in a row of longer strings in another dataframe (big_df). Below is a dummy experiment with some nested for loops.

I am trying to use an increment function to add 1 to the column "z" in big_df, when str_detect evaluates to true, finding a word from dumb_df.

When I run the below code, i get an error.

```
big <- c("happy birth day to you", "sorry bad day, man", "happy old man")
dumb <- c("happy", "birth", "day", "sorry", "man", "you")

big_df <- data.frame(x = c(big), y = c(1:3), z = c(0, 0, 0))
dumb_df <- data.frame(x = c(dumb), y = c(1:length(dumb)))

inc <- function(x)
{
  eval.parent(substitute(x <- x + 1))
}

for (i in big_df$x) {
  for (j in dumb_df$x) {
    if (str_detect(i, j)) {
      inc(big_df$z[i])
    }
  }
}
```

When i change the last piece of code before the curly braces to
`inc(big_df$z)`
I get closer, but the "z" column just returns the same number for each row (9). the count for the rows should be 4, 3, 2 (sums to 9).

How can I get the "z" column to reflect the count of dumb_df strings in big_df? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you can use nested `sapply` which is similar to the nested `for` loop iterating over each keyword in `dumb_df$x` for each string in `big_df$x`.

```
big_df$z <- colSums(sapply(big_df$x, function(x) sapply(dumb_df$x, grepl, x)))
big_df

#                       x y z
#1 happy birth day to you 1 4
#2     sorry bad day, man 2 3
#3          happy old man 3 2
```

---

Using `str_count` from `stringr` will avoid `sapply` you can combine the pattern in one string using `paste0`.

```
big_df$z <- stringr::str_count(big_df$x, paste0(dumb_df$x, collapse = '|'))
```

Comment: oh yeah got it. is there an explanation of why `collapse = '|' ` does what it does here? i see if you run it without the collapse argument it just gives the last iteration, in 0s and 1s. I checked the documentation and i think i understand what collapse arg does, but I am not clear on how it works in this case.

Comment: In regex, when we want to find more than one word we separate them using `|`. If you want to count for only 'abc' in a text you can do `str_count(text, 'abc')`. If you want to count for 'abc' and 'def' you can do that by `str_count(text, 'abc|def')`. The same logic applies here with `paste0(dumb_df$x, collapse = '|')` we create a pattern programatically to look for.